# How to improve a function?

Tags: c, optimization, gprof

I have a program that counts 2 to the power 26 and the root of result number.

Program's source code is contained in several files and I compiled it by makefile with `-pg` flag. I run it by `gprof ./main` and as a result I got:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name    
 51.95      1.73     1.73       52     0.03     0.03  very_smart_add
 32.73      2.82     1.09 67108863     0.00     0.00  give_me_sum
 11.71      3.21     0.39       13     0.03     0.16  the_middle_of
  3.60      3.33     0.12       26     0.00     0.05  give_me_product
  0.00      3.33     0.00       13     0.00     0.13  the_middle_of2
  0.00      3.33     0.00        1     0.00     1.21  give_me_power
  0.00      3.33     0.00        1     0.00     2.12  square_root
```

I want to improve the most time consuming function but I have no idea how to do this. What can be done in this case?

**Files:**

`part1.c`:

```
long long give_me_product(long long a, long long b);

long long give_me_power(long long a, long long b)
{
    long long ret = 1;
    while (b--)
    {
        ret = give_me_product(a, ret);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

`part2.c`:

```
long long give_me_sum(long long a, long long b);

long long give_me_product(long long a, long long b)
{
    long long ret = 0;
    while (b--)
    {
        ret = give_me_sum(a, ret);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

`part3.c`:

```
long long give_me_sum(long long a, long long b)
{
    long long ret = 0;
    while (a--)
    {
        ret++;
    }
    return ret + b;
    while (b--)
    {
        ret++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

`sqrt.c`:

```
#define EPS 0.0000000001
#define STEP 1.0

/* This function adds two numbers. */
double very_smart_add(double a, double b)
{
    while (b >= STEP)
    {
        a += STEP;
        b -= STEP;
    }
    a += b;
    return a;
}

double the_middle_of2(double a, double b)
{
    double l = a, r = b;
    double check, m;
    while (1)
    {
        m = very_smart_add(l, r)/2;
        check = very_smart_add(m, m);
        if (check > very_smart_add(a, b) + EPS)
            r = m;
        else if (check < very_smart_add(a, b) - EPS)
            l = m;
        else
            return m;
    }
}
double the_middle_of(double a, double b)
{
    double r = 0;
    double s = a + b;
    while (r + r < s)
    {
        r += 1.0;
    }
    return the_middle_of2(r - 1.0, s - (r - 1.0));
}

double square_root(double x)
{
    double l = 0, r = x;
    double check, m;
    while (1)
    {
        m = the_middle_of(l, r);
        check = m * m;
        if (check > x + EPS)
            r = m;
        else if (check < x - EPS)
            l = m;
        else
            return m;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to be optimized for that specific numbers or for a general case?

Comment: TL/DR, but `sqrt(2^26) = 2 << 13 = 8192`. No calculation is required.

Comment: ...and 2^26 fits a 32-bit `int` anyway.

Comment: Is `give_me_sum()` supposed to be so terribly inefficient? Its top half returns `a + b` and its bottom half is never reached.

Comment: Your profile says `very_smart_add` is the time sink, so I would start there, and maybe explain what is so *smart* about it.

Comment: Additionally, `very_smart_add()` is _not_ very smart.

Comment: What's the purpose of this specific implementation?

Comment: Anyway, what is this question about? How to improve the a triangular wheel I've invented?

Comment: @mah, yes, it is supposed to be so inefficient and my task in here is to find inefficiency and correct it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Question is about where to change this code to make it working faster.

Comment: @krzyhub assuming you're supposed to use the output of gprof to identify where it's inefficient (and not simple code inspection)... is your question `How do I interpret the output of gprof?`? What part of it do you not understand? Perhaps making a call tree and correlating it to gprof's output will help you understand, but it now seems your question is off-topic for SO.

Comment: @AB I am looking for improvement for this specific case. Just `2^26`

Comment: @krzyhub here is the improvement of this case: `return 8192;`.

Comment: I think that some operations could be replaced by other, faster and this is what I am looking for.

Comment: No, really. Gradual refactoring of a rubbish code is a bad idea. It's better to ask yourself, "what should it do" and pick an appropriate algorithm and implement it. It will give you the ultimate "improvement".

Comment: Well the fastest solution that involves some operations is the one already provided: 2<<13 You can't go faster than shifting bit wise on power of operations.

Comment: For example: I found out that `while` loop was unnecessary. I think that something else like this can be still found.

Comment: 2^13 = 8192 while 2<<13 = 16384. ;-)

Comment: @dlask Ooops. My fault, I guess :)

Comment: @dlask, my bad it should be 1<<13

Comment: @krzyhub What's the main problem? Can you identify the most time consuming function? Can you change it somehow? Is it faster then?

Comment: for example: `very_smart_add` works better without while loop

Comment: This is no code review site.

Comment: @Olaf well there's **[codereview.se]** if you have real working code that's ready to be peer reviewed.... oh gosh, I read that as "there is no code review site" ....my bad ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug: Sorry, I should have linked that. I read the question as such that he is trying to optimize running code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a homework assignment, but I'll offer one idea to simplify addition - get rid of unnecessary while loops and maybe detect overflow.

Moving this to community wiki.

```
long long give_me_sum(long long a, long long b) {
  #if NEED_TO_PREVENT_UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR
  if (a >= 0) {
    if (b > LLONG_MAX - a) return LLONG_MAX;
  } else {
    if (b < LLONG_MIN - a) return LLONG_MIN;
  }
  #endif
  return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You `give_me_power` function is of O(n). You can optimize it to O(log n).

```
long long give_me_power(long long a, long long b)
{
    long long ret = 1;
    while (b)
    {
        if ( b & 1) {
            ret *= a;
            b--;
        } else {
            a *= a;
            b >>= 1;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```